# (unity) I want to download image from URL for each button of my app but it shows just last button one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

All buttons and text can show well but the image just shows only last button. when I try to click to check `user.value.imageUrl`, it's correct. I don't know what is wrong, please help me. I think IEnumerator has something I am missing.

my code is:

```
  void CreateButton()
    {
        FirebaseRestClent.GetUsers(users =>
        {
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                StartCoroutine(downloadImage(user.Value.imageUrl));
                var clone = Instantiate(button,m_transform) as GameObject;
                var modelBtn = clone.GetComponent<Button>();

                imageToUpdate = modelBtn.GetComponent<Image>();
                title = modelBtn.GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
                title.text = user.Value.saveFile;

                //Debug.Log($"{user.Value.modelUrl} {user.Value.saveFile} {user.Value.imageUrl}");
                modelBtn.onClick.AddListener(delegate { 
                    Debug.Log(user.Value.modelUrl + user.Value.saveFile + user.Value.imageUrl);
                    dlManager.PlayModel(user.Value.modelUrl, user.Value.saveFile,user.Value.musicUrl,false);
                    //dlManager.PlayModel(user.Value.modelUrl, user.Value.saveFile, false);
                });

            }
        });
        
    }
    IEnumerator downloadImage(string url)
    {

        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url);

        DownloadHandler handle = www.downloadHandler;

        //Send Request and wait
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isHttpError || www.isNetworkError)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Error while Receiving: " + www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Success");

            //Load Image
            Texture2D texture2d = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);
            Sprite sprite = null;
            sprite = Sprite.Create(texture2d, new Rect(0, 0, 326, texture2d.height), Vector2.zero);
            imageToUpdate.sprite = sprite;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you always overwrite the same `imageToUpdate` field reference in your loop so most probably all results get written into the `Image` component of the very last user.

You should rather simply pass the image reference on to the routine

```
void CreateButton()
{
    FirebaseRestClent.GetUsers(users =>
    {
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            var clone = Instantiate(button, m_transform) as GameObject;
            var modelBtn = clone.GetComponent<Button>();

            var image = modelBtn.GetComponent<Image>();
            // instead of storing it in a class field rather 
            // pass the image reference into the Coroutine
            StartCoroutine(downloadImage(user.Value.imageUrl, image));

            title = modelBtn.GetComponentInChildren<Text>(true);
            title.text = user.Value.saveFile;

            modelBtn.onClick.AddListener(()=>
            { 
                Debug.Log(user.Value.modelUrl + user.Value.saveFile + user.Value.imageUrl);
                dlManager.PlayModel(user.Value.modelUrl, user.Value.saveFile, user.Value.musicUrl, false);
            });
        }
    });
}

IEnumerator downloadImage(string url, Image targetImage)
{
    using(www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url))
    {
        //Send Request and wait
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isHttpError || www.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error while Receiving: " + www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Success");

            //Load Image
            var texture2d = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);
            var sprite = Sprite.Create(texture2d, new Rect(0, 0, 326, texture2d.height), Vector2.zero);
            targetImage.sprite = sprite;
        }
    }
}
```